# Convolution operator in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution

[image]

This is exercise 10.16 from *Measure and Integral* by *Wheeden and Zygmund*, the major part is easy, but what exactly is the "generalization"? I'm not sure what to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you had the assumption
$$
 \|Tf\|_p \leq M\|f\|_p \quad \forall f
$$
and then you were able to prove that
$$
\|Tf\|_{p'} \leq M \|f\|_{p'} \quad \forall f
$$
with $p'$ being the conjugate exponent.

Now for the generalization you have the assumption
$$
 \|Tf\|_q \leq M\|f\|_p \quad \forall f
$$
with $p\neq q$.
The case $p=q$ was already the first part, and hence the word "generalization".
The way i understand it, you should now prove a result of the type
$$
 \|Tf\|_r \leq \tilde M\|f\|_s \quad \forall f
$$
with suitable $r,s$ and $\tilde M$ (An important part of the problem is to figure out which values for $r,s$ should be chosen).

Comment: Is $M' = M \sup || g ||_p$ where $\sup$ is taking all $g\in L^q$, $r = q'$, $s = q'$ valid? That's the closest I get.

Comment: I did not try to solve the problem so i dont know. It looks like $M'=\infty$ from your comment, this is probably not ok.